# Determining whether a system is linear or not having the impulse response

Tags: signal-analysis, convolution, linear-systems

I got many exercises where I have to determine the response of a system to an input signal

The only things i have are the impulse response and the input signal.
I was thinking I could use the convolution to get the output, but to proceed that way I should know the system is linear and time invariant, none of which is specified

Is there a way to determine if a system is whether LTI or not by knowing the impulse response?

As an example I have this exercise right here

*What is the response to the input signal* $x[n]=2^n u[n]$

*Knowing the impulse response is*
$h[n] = u[n]$

More than resolving this particular problem I'm concerned on how to proceed in general when I get those type of exercises

Answer (score 2):

In general, the term "impulse response" doesn't mean much if the system is nonlinear, and a time-varying system will have an impulse response that depends on, well, time.

So if I tell you the impulse response is $h[n] = u[n]$, then that implies that the system is linear and time invariant.  If I tell you that the impulse response is $h(\tau, t) = \sin(\omega t) u(\tau)$ then that implies that the system is linear and time varying.

If I tell you a system is nonlinear and then give you an impulse response then without defining what the term means in the context of what I'm saying *I'm in error*, because an impulse response implies the system obeys superposition, and that, in turn, implies linearity.

Comment: I know I'm being pedantic, but I don't see why an impulse response implies superposition. A non-linear system has a perfectly well-defined impulse response, just like a linear system. I would put it like this instead: for the impulse response to be **useful**, the system must be linear; conversely, when someone gives you an impulse response $h(t)$ (or $h(\tau,t)$) it is assumed by convention that the system is LTI (or LTV).

Comment: Agreed with @MBaz, I think these descriptions are more for the _transfer function_.

Answer (score 1):

A non-linear and/or time-varying system cannot be completely described by its response to an impulse.

(Linear time-varying systems can be described by a two-dimensional impulse response, but that's beyond the scope here.)

So, if you're given the impulse response of a system, you can be sure that the system is LTI, and, consequently, the output signal is given by the convolution of the input signal and the impulse response.